# Approximate chances of rolling primes on unknown-sided dice

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, dice

There is a function for approximating the number of primes below a certain integer

What would be the function for determining the chances of rolling a prime number when rolling *n* number of *d*-sided dice?

If I throw four twenty-sided dice, the chances that the values will add up to a prime number can be *precisely* answered, but what is the equation using only the $\frac{x}{log(x)}$ approximation of the prime-counting function?

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a clean approximation. The exact formula would be
$$\sum_{i=1}^{nd}P(\text{X = i})I_{\text{primes}}(i)$$
where $X$ follows an Irwin-Hall distribution (approximately normal) and $I_{\text{primes}}(i)$ is the indicator function denoting whether $i$ is prime. You cannot apply the $x/\log(x)$ insight because it would require the distribution of $X$ is uniform, which is clearly violated.